# Getting an error when trying to set input_formats for Django TimeField

Tags: django, modelform, timefield

I am using the following model to represent a Class:

```
class Class(models.Model):
  course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  day = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=WEEK_DAYS)
  timing = models.TimeField(input_formats = ['%I:%M %p', ])
  room = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

I want to set my TimeField's format to 12 hours with am and pm. Django's documentation mentions using an input_formats argument to accomplish this [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#timefield). However, when I run makemigrations, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "D:\Applications\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "D:\Applications\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 347, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "D:\Applications\Python\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "D:\Applications\Python\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "D:\Applications\Python\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "D:\Applications\Python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\plannerly\timetable\models.py", line 15, in <module>
    class Class(models.Model):
  File "D:\plannerly\timetable\models.py", line 18, in Class
    timing = models.TimeField(input_formats = ['%I:%M %p', ])
  File "D:\Applications\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 2146, in __init__
    super().__init__(verbose_name, name, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'input_formats'
```

I'm not really sure whats causing this. Any ideas?

Comment: you're confusing Model fields with Form fields.

Comment: here's the [`TimeField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#timefield)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input_formats` is for `forms.DateField()`[1]. It is *not* a `model.DateField()`[2] option.

You have to set `input_fomats=[]` in your form, not in your models.

> [1] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#timefield
>
> [2] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField

Comment: I see. Thank you for the help.